# Wordpress PHP if iframe external domain then

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to make something like title say's.
Some friendly websites use a widget with iframe of my front page and i get traffic.

The problem is that all the traffic goes to home page. I want to share the visitors of the iframe to random posts without to edit the external iframe widget of the friend's site's.

i have search and finded a code but has a bug and with this code i cant access my homepage, the home page is redirecting all visitors to random posts.

How can i make the home page redirecting if it is only in iframe?

```
    <?php
$continue = 0;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {

    //correct domain:
    $ar=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if( strpos($ar['host'], 'mydomain.com') === false ){
    } else {
        $continue = 1;
    }

}

if($continue == 0){ ?>
    <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>

<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand' ); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php wp_redirect ( get_permalink () ); exit; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is confusing. Why do you need to store "continue" as a variable? Why don't you just add something like this to the top of your page?

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $ar=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if( strpos($ar['host'], 'mydomain.com') === false ){
      header('Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand');
      exit();
    }

  }
?>
```

(Just reusing your code - basically, check if the site is loaded in an iframe and the homepage was requested - if so, redirect to the random page)

Comment: Nice is working. I added this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-random-post-in-wordpress/ to my functions.php, edited the url and its works.

Thanks